# activate a dropdown list when click a radio button

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have a form and in it I have a radio button with two choices (Yes or No). After that I have a dropdown list. I want to activate the list only when the choice "Yes" is clicked and be inactivated otherwise. I have done it with JQuery. However, it doesn't work. Not only the list is not activated, but also the "Yes" value of the radio button cannot be checked!!! Below is the code:

This is the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="Married" id="MarriedYes" value="Yes" onclick="hideStudentChildren()" required>YES
<input type="radio" name="Married" id="MarriedNo" value="No" required>NO
```

This is the dropdown list:

```
<select id="selectChildrenStudent" name="ChildrenStudent" class="required"  disabled="true" required>
                            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>--Choose--</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
```

And this is the JQuery code:

```
function hideStudentChildren(){
if ($("#MarriedYes").prop("checked", true)) {
    $("#selectChildrenStudent").removeAttr("disabled");
}
if ($("#MarriedYes").prop("checked", false)) {
    $("#selectChildrenStudent").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

}

Please any help.....thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do simple as below...

```
<input type="radio" name="Married" id="MarriedYes" value="Yes" onclick="hideStudentChildren()" required>YES
<input type="radio" name="Married" id="MarriedNo" value="No" onclick="hideStudentChildren()" required>NO

<script>
function hideStudentChildren(){
if ($("#MarriedYes").is(":checked")) {
    $("#selectChildrenStudent").removeAttr("disabled");
}
if ($("#MarriedNo").is(":checked")) {
    $("#selectChildrenStudent").attr("disabled","disabled");
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: It works but only by half! When I checked the "Yes" it was activated the list, but when I checked after (just to see what will happen...) the "No", it didn't deactivated.

Comment: It must work my friend. Have you checked the line : <input type="radio" name="Married" id="MarriedNo" value="No" onclick="hideStudentChildren()" required>NO

Comment: Ok guys, it worked....I just forgot to put the onclick to the "No" radio button! Thanks...

Comment: And how can I put the empty value to the list when the "No" is checked? Because, if I check the "Yes" and then choose a value from the list, when I check again the "No", the list doesn't change...

Comment: Inside if condition for NO just place : if ($("#MarriedNo").is(":checked")) {
    $("#selectChildrenStudent").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#selectChildrenStudent").val("");
}

Answer (score 0):

**add same class in your radio buttons**

```
<input class="rndMarried" type="radio" name="Married" id="MarriedYes" value="Yes" required>YES
<input class="rndMarried" type="radio" name="Married" id="MarriedNo" value="No" required>NO

$(document).delegate(".rndMarried","change",function(){
    //alert($(this).val());
    var values=$(this).val();
    if(values=="Yes") {
        $("#selectChildrenStudent").attr("disabled", true);  
    }
    else {
    $("#selectChildrenStudent").attr("disabled", false);  
    }
});
```